# Adding api versions to Cakephp modal view controller system

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using CAKEPHP for creating my Application apis,

Currently I have few controllers in `

> app/controllers/{UsersController, AdminController, StoresController}

` etc

I am accessing my controllers as  //users/

However I want to add versioning system in cakephp

Something like

```
<ip>/<foldername>/v1/users/<action>
<ip>/<foldername>/v2/users/<action>
```

I tried creating a Folder inside `Controllers/` as `Controllers/v1/UsersController.php`

However I am unable to access it.
How can i configure my routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm quite confused about CakePHP version you are using (you tagged cakephp-3.0, and folder structure you used in question resembles that of 2.x), but both 2.x and 3.x versions have common concept called Prefix Routing, which is what you should use here. Below example assumes CakePHP 3.x:

You need to create directories (v1, v2) inside your Controller directory. Next, create individual controllers in that folder, remembering that namespace should also reflect this structure:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller\v1;
use App\Controller\AppController;

class UsersController extends AppController {
    //...
}
```

Final step is to configure routing in your routes.php. Example below:

```
Router::prefix("v1", function (RouteBuilder $routes){
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

More info can be found here:
[Prefix Routing](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing)

**For CakePHP 2.x things are little different:**

In v2.x, you should NOT create folders inside Controller directory. All prefixed and unprefixed functions will reside in single controllers, eg.

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
    /**
    * Unprefixed function
    */
    public function login(){
    }

    /**
    * Prefix v1
    */
    public function v1_login(){
    }

    /**
    * Prefix v2
    */
    public function v2_login(){
    }
}
```

Next, you need to configure these prefixes in your app/Config/core.php file like so:

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('v1', 'v2'));
```

After this, you should be able to access your actions with v1 and v2 prefixes, eg `yourapp/v1/users/login` will map to `UsersController::v1_login()` and `yourapp/v2/users/login` to `UsersController::v2_login()`.

More info in documentation for 2.x: [Prefix Routing v2.x](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing)

Comment: Sorry about the wrong tag, It is indeed 2.o let me try your code and get back

Comment: If it's 2.x, steps are little different. Please check this documentation, there is step-by-step instruction how to setup this: https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing

Comment: I would like a little guidance, as per documentation Router::connect('v2', array('controller' => 'xxx', 'action' => 'xx', 'xx'));  I have 10+ controllers in v2 directly, do i have to define controllers and their actions ?

Comment: Standard routing (:prefix/:controller/:action) should work immediately after configuration of prefixes.

Comment: I Tried Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('v2')); in core.php and Router::connect(
    "/{$prefix}/:controller/:action/*",
    array('prefix' => $prefix, $prefix => true)
); in routes.php, Create a folder v2 and copied all files in it. Also given name spaces as above however its still reading Main root files and not inside v2, my path is <fodlername>/v2/users/login